# Absolute continuity of probability measure wrt Lebesgue measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am a bit dumbfounded by this problem as it has always been given in the build up to an application of the Radon-Nikodym theorem.

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ is a probability space. Suppose that
>   $Y:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $Y(\Omega) = \mathbb{R}$, is a continuous random variable with
>   density $f(y)$. Define $$\mathcal{C} = \{Y^{-1}(B): B \in \mathcal{B}\}$$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-field
>   defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Next, define $\mu(Y^{-1}(B)) = \lambda(B)$
>   for any $Y^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{C}$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue
>   measure in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $P \ll \mu$.

We know that $P \ll \mu$ if $\mu(A) = 0$ implies $P(A) = 0$ but I am not certain how to prove this relationship without more context about $P$.

Thanks in advanced for the help!

Comment: I Have a question: Why is $\mu$ well defined? Imagine $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, but $Y(\Omega)=[0,1]$. Then $2=\lambda([0,2])=\mu(\Omega)=\lambda([0,1])=1$. I think I got something wrong somewhere.

Comment: I edited the problem a bit. In a different step of the exercise, we show that $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\sigma$-field and $\mu$ is a measure given $Y(\Omega) = \mathbb{R}$. You are correct that the missing condition is necessary for $\mu$ to be well defined.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by humanStampedist we cannot, in general,  define a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal C$ by $\mu(Y^{-1} (B))=\lambda (B)$. I would interpret the problem as follows: suppose there exists a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal C$ such that $\mu(Y^{-1} (B))=\lambda (B)$. Then $P<<\mu$ on $\mathcal C$. To prove this let $\mu(Y^{-1}(B))=0$. Then $\lambda (B)=0$. Hence $P(Y^{-1}(B))=\int_B f(x) \, dx=0$.

Comment: This making a bit more sense. To clarify the last piece, is an equivalent notation $P(Y^{-1}(B)) = \int_{B} f(y) \lambda(dy) = 0$?